# SQL Query, cannot find the right query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm hosting a platform where users get SQL logs, I want to make some kind of highscore for it so there like a top 10 of users who got the most logs.

All registered users get their own 'ID', in the logs the user 'ID' is displayed as: 'id'. So in users 'ID' is in capitals and in 'logs' it is without capitals.
I would like to have some kind of query like this:

```
SELECT username,ID FROM users ORDER BY COUNT (id) FROM logs LIMIT 10;
```

But this does not work so maybe someone of you have a solution?

Comment: You should look up on JOINS, you can do like what you're doing now with double FROM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you'll need to join the table and use the group function, really useful for what you're trying to achieve:

```
 SELECT users.username, users.id 
    FROM users  
    LEFT JOIN logs on users.id = logs.id
    GROUP BY users.id
    ORDER BY COUNT (logs.id) 
    LIMIT 10;
```

Or try with aliases:

```
 SELECT users.username as u, users.id as i 
    FROM users  
    LEFT JOIN logs on users.id = logs.id
    GROUP BY i
    ORDER BY COUNT (logs.id) 
    LIMIT 10;
```

Try this to achieve the log count:

```
 SELECT users.username, users.id, COUNT(logs.id) as quantity
    FROM users  
    LEFT JOIN logs on users.id = logs.id
    GROUP BY users.id
    ORDER BY COUNT(logs.id) 
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @Jeroen - Its because `ID` field is present in both the tables. Use Alas name to differentiate it

Comment: ORDER BY COUNT(logs.id) , that space had to be deleted between COUNT and ( ////
Now it shows the username and user ID
Is it possible to count the amount of logs to show: username, amount of logs?

Comment: Try that. Should add a column called quantity which will be a count of the rows in logs

Comment: Tried that, it gives 3 rows, where quantity isn't working: http://gyazo.com/74dfb7311c2c5a29c95198cd40d371e9

Comment: It works fine for me with some dummy data i've setup. I'm wondering if the problem is with how your database is structured. Can you tell what all the columns are in your logs table? The id isn't the auto-incrementing primary key is it?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/c69415f1eb4b2c644d8ed2729637dbe4 This is the structure in logs, first two don't really matter. /// http://gyazo.com/ef342b4c91e6539a1202baa452cf73e0 This is the structure in users, AUTO_INCREMENT is so the ID increases when a new account is created

Answer (score 0):

Simple `Inner Join` should work

```
SELECT U.username,U.ID 
FROM users U
INNER JOIN logs L 
on U.id = L.id 
Group by U.username,U.ID 
ORDER BY COUNT (id) FROM  LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User.username, User.ID, Count(Log.id) LogCount
FROM users User 
LEFT JOIN logs Log
    ON User.ID = Log.id
GROUP BY User.ID, User.username
ORDER BY LogCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```